# How to Check if Macbook Lid is closed via Terminal?

Tags: grep, osx-mountain-lion, cron, wakeup

I'm running OS X 10.8 (Mountain Lion). I was wondering if there was a terminal command to check if the macbook pro's lid is currently closed. If I used grep, what would I be looking for exactly, and where?

The reason I ask is because I have cron jobs scheduled to run every 30 minutes. However, crontab doesn't run when the computer is sleeping/hibernating. My solution was to use pmset to schedule wakes every 30 minutes. However, I need a way to put my computer back to sleep on the condition that the lid is currently closed. I don't want my computer to be awake for too long with the lid closed i.e. awake all night when I'm sleeping because that could damage the screen.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState -d 4 | grep AppleClamshellState  | head -1
```

Tested and works on 10.7.*, found [here](http://www.dsign.caltech.edu/erik/Misc/clamshellstate.pl).

Update 2019-02-26:

Still works on macOS 10.14.3 Mojave

Comment: `No` means open, `Yes` means closed

Comment: Also works on macos 10.14!
I'm checking for closed state with that:

`ioreg -r -k AppleClamshellState -d 4 | grep AppleClamshellState  | head -1 | grep Yes`

If i printed some text - the lid is closed. And vice versa.

Comment: Also works on macos 10.15!

Comment: `-d 1` is enough. (`-d`: Limit tree traversal to the specified depth.)

Comment: Also works on 10.15.7!

Comment: Also works on 11.2.3

Comment: Working on Ventura (macOS 13), Apple Silicon to boot!

Comment: To complete the list - it also works on macOS 12.7.3. ^^

Comment: Also works on Sonoma 14.3